# How to get a specific row as first result, then the rest of the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wonder if it's possible to have a query that will return a result set with a specific row as first element, then the rest, ordered by a specific row.

I tried this:

```
declare @testId int

select @testId = (select TestID from Tests Where FileID='111' AND TestDate='2010-01-01')

select * from Tests where TestId=@TestId

union

select * from Tests where TestId <> @TestId and FileID='111' order by TestDate desc
```

That doesn't really work as it outputs a regular SELECT ordered by TestDate, descending.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

EDIT: This query is used to feed a .NET DataTable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tests 
Where FileNumber = '111' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN AppointmentDT='2010-01-01' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC 
    , AppointmentDT DESC
```

Comment: I get this error: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator. AFAIK, that's already the case.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme: i don't understand the requirement anymore. Why do you need `UNION` at all? I thought that was just a try to get it ordered which didn't work, so you've aksed this question. If you want to use the `UNION` you have to do that in a sub-query and you need to apply the `ORDER BY` on the outer query.

Comment: I edited the query in the question. Maybe that'll help. If I don't UNION, then I get the only result of the first SELECT. The requirement is that I get the result of the first SELECT (as the first row of a result set) then the rest of them, ordered by TestDate.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme: i've also edited my answer. Maybe it's now clearer that it shows the row which applies to the condition(s) first, then all other rows(ordered by `TestDate desc`).

Comment: I think he needs it all.   where FileID='111'

Comment: Yes, Francis -- @TimSchmelter is saying you can take his answer as a whole, not just the Order By.  It should create the whole result set, with the special first row.

Comment: @Blam: It's not clear. However, then he just needs to remove the `TestDate='2010-01-01'` from the order-by. I've taken it from his first query.

Comment: @TimSchmelter look at the second.  where TestId <> atTestId and FileID='111'

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the confusion Tim. All the result need to have FileID='111' as criteria, it just that the first row needs to be from an added criteria (AppointmentDT = '2010-01-01'). I used your answer and did: SELECT * FROM Tests
Where FileNumber = '111'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN AppointmentDT='2010-01-01' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
        , AppointmentDT DESC and this works fine. If you edit your answer, I'll flag it as answered.